# 「安い」って英語からきた表現？

Tags: translation, words, metaphor

皆さんこんにちは、

日本語で質問を聞かせていただきますので、ご協力ください。
回答やコメントなどは、日本語か英語、どちらの言語でも喜んで読みます。

では。
此間友達と喋っていて好みの話をしていた時一人が「ホラー映画やB級映画が大好き」と言うやいなや「あなた安いな〜」ともう一人が反応しました。

その「安い」は、英語に「cheap」と直訳すれば同じ意味が通じるそうなので、もしかしたら英語からきた表現じゃないかと思ってきました。(その逆もありえるのですが、あんまり想像できません)。JLUの皆さん、どう思いますか？偶然に意味も言葉も合うか、または英語とかから日本語に導入された表現でしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: Could explain more clearly why you think there might be an influence from English? The word 安い is a very old one in Japanese and the meaning of "inexpensive" is at least 1000 years old too. I'm not sure I see what gap the English influence is supposed to fill.

Comment: Matt: I believe that "you're cheap" means something like a cynical yet friendly "you're satisfied with so little" in English.  I'm pretty sure I heard that a lot.  Now, hearing *literally* the same expression in Japanese makes me curious about the origin of this expression.  Is it a co-incidence, or an import?

Comment: [[ その逆もあり**うる**のですが .]]

Comment: @istrasci: Some people use ありえる, and I think that both ありうる (partly preserving classical Japanese grammar) and ありえる (adopting modern Japanese grammar) are accepted in modern Japanese.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - Accepted by whom??  "Irregardless" is widely accepted in English, but that doesn't make it a correct word.  Just curious.

Comment: @istrasci: By general fluent speakers of Japanese.  [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&index=01948700&pagenum=1) (sense 5) is more careful than me, and states 特に5の終止形・連体形は「うる」を用いることが多い.

Comment: @istraci: [completely JLU-off-topic but] I'd really like to know who "widely accepts" irregardless in English: last I check it was still considered a full-on *barbarism* (and not even close enough to common to be defended from a descriptivist standpoint).

Comment: I wouldn't use irregardless myself, but I wouldn't regard (ha!) someone who used it as a barbarian. M-W sez that it is still a long way from acceptance in written language (http://i.word.com/idictionary/irregardless) but clearly it is (or was, at one time) accepted by enough speakers to be noticeable to the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Enno Shioji that the use of the expression あなた安いな for “You are so cheap (= You are so easily satisfied)” is uncommon in Japanese.  I do not think that it has been used in Japanese for a long time.  However, this usage definitely exists; we can see several webpages which contain this usage of 安い (I searched “安い人だ” in Google and chose suitable usages from the search results).

- [おれって安い人だなー](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Gaius_Petronius/20110412)
- [たかだかハワイでそう思える僕は安い人だ](http://brst.jp/?day=20110722)
- [大臣ならともかくあと何日続くかわからない政務官で買われるとは随分安い人だ](http://kashiwataro.iza.ne.jp/blog/entry/2342830/allcmt/)

(The third example above may or may not be in the same category because it may be regarded as a metaphor which describes a person as a commercial product.)

It may be the case that this usage of 安い was derived from the usual meaning “costing little” of the word 安い by the metaphor, independently of English, just in the same way as the English word “cheap” acquired its “easily satisfied” meaning.  Or it may be the case that the expression in Japanese originates from the literal translation of the English expression “You are cheap.”  I do not know how to tell which is true.

安い has a different but perhaps related usage: [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%AE%89%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0) (sense 2) lists the meaning “insignificant” with an example 安く見られる (considered insignificant, underestimated), and [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E5%AE%89%E3%81%8F%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) has a separate entry for 安く見られる.  My impression is that 安く見られたものだ (literally “I am considered insignificant”) is a common expression in Japanese to express dissatisfaction or anger of the speaker.  This is similar to your example in that 安い is used to describe a person, but different because your example does not mean “You are insignificant.”

Answer (score 3):

私の理解では、その「安い」は相手の予想通り**簡単に**入り込んでしまう、信じてしまう、騙されやすいなどの意味だと思います。似たような言い方で、「あたた**単純**だね」とか「あなた**天然**だね」とかあると思います。

あとホラー映画は他の映画よりシーンが少なく屋内で作成できるのが多いため制作費がかなり低いと言われていますので、金額が安いという意味で、安物で満足出来ているという意味もあるかもしれません。

で、個人的には英語からきた表現ではないと思います。

Comment: 意味は「単純」があっていると思いますが、ホラー映画の作成金額とは関係ない。「ピザすらあれば一緒にどこにも行ってあげる」とか言う人に対しても使えるような気がする表現なのです。

Comment: I would not interpret 安い in the question as “簡単に入り込んでしまう、信じてしまう、騙されやすい.”  I interpret あなた安いな as “You are easily satisfied,” and the low budget of horror movies is a factor that contributes to “easily.”  The same explanation applies to ピザさえ (すら is inappropriate here) あれば一緒にどこにも行ってあげる人.  Note that ピザ is easy to get, and therefore this person is easily satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

日本語で答えるのはちょっと恥ずかしい…

YOUの答えと同じくて、この「安い」の意味は「単純」と似ている。

だから、僕が「あなた安いな〜」を英語に翻訳したら、`"You're easy to please"`、になると思う。略して、`"You're easy"`も大丈夫だと思う。

Comment: 「どう英訳するか」って質問ではなくて「英語でも日本語でも「安い」を使うことは偶然か？」って質問ですよ。(英語では"you're (so) cheap"って言うよね？)

Comment: うん、でも翻訳したら、違いが明解になると思う。英語で"You're cheap"と日本語で「安いな」の意味はかなり違う。僕にとって、"You're cheap"はすごく侮辱的な。

Answer (score 2):

「あなた安いね」っていう表現はあまり聞いたことないですね。ひょっとすると聞きまちがいかも知れません。「分かりやすい」ならしっくりきますが、これを「やすい」と略することはないと思います。ちなみに、この時のやすいは安いではなくて「易い」です。
もし「分かりやすい」の聞き間違いだったとすれば、ここでは「あなたの考え方や趣味が予測し易い」という意味になり、転じて「趣味のレベルが低い」というニュアンスも持ち得ます。

もし本当に「安い」とだけ言ってcheapに近い意味で使っているなら、そのコミュニティで最近できた言葉なのかも。その場合は英語由来の可能性は高いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 聞き間違いではありません。面白いと思ってたのでそれを言ったとすぐ確認して、それが言えると肯定されました。英語ど「you're so cheap」という意味で言いたようです。海外滞在経験のない三十代の「普通な」日本人の女の人だったので、どのコミュだろうか僕には分かりません。

Answer (score 2):

英語も日本語もそれぞれ独立にこの使い方にたどり着いた可能性もあるから、英語に影響されたとは言いきれませんね。ただ、日本語においてはかなり現代的な使い方だと否めません。

Comment: ありそうな表現だと思いますか？または聞いたことがありますか？

Comment: 少なくとも現代文学(マンガニメを含む)においてはよく聞く表現です。